# RFID Programming With VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, rfid

I'm trying to use RFID Contactless Smart Card (T8/D8 Series) for my final project.
But i have problem acessing the dcrf32.dll file in my form.

There are 3 things included in RFID Package, (therefore : 12 smartcards, an usb port, and a driver CD)

In the driver CD, there are so many sample project in some programming language, except VB.NET, i tried them one by one, and that's work.

There is a folder named "win32-dll", it have 3 files inside (`dcrf32.dll`, `dcrf32.h`, `dcrf32.lib`). I have to copy them all in every sample program that i want to use.
[image]

They also have example in VB.6, when i try to run it, no problems at all. It works. 
(i also put those 3 dcrf files in the `%windows%\System32` folder).

But, when i try to build my own project with Visual Studio 2010 and using VB.NET programming language, i have a problem calling the dcrf32.dll file.

I migrate the VB6 source code to VB.NET, it has error when giving parameters to dc_init function.
Can anybody help me? Where is my fault?

Here are the links that important to solve my problems :
[Here](http://www.4shared.com/folder/eo-MhC5_/SolvingProblems.html)

I just need help with my first button, and you don't have to help me with the other button like in VB 6 example program.

I just wanna know how to connect the dcrf32 files, and why in VB.NET it has error but in VB 6 it works properly.

I wonder it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is dealing with your Declare Functions and the fact there are changes to the size of integers and longs etc. in VB.Net. Look at this [Link](http://www.vbmigration.com/Resources/detmigratingfromvb6.aspx?Id=7) and this Code Project [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/PInvoke.aspx) on using PInvoke.

i.e.  An Integer in VB6 is a Short in VB.Net, A Long in VB6 is an Integer in VB.Net. The % in your Declares is a VB6 Integer and will become a short.

```
Declare Auto Function dc_init Lib "dcrf32.dll" (ByVal port as Short, ByVal baud As Integer) As Integer
Declare Auto Function dc_exit Lib "dcrf32.dll" (ByVal icdev As Integer) As Short
Declare Auto Function dc_request Lib "dcrf32.dll" (ByVal icdev As Integer, ByVal mode as Short, tagtype As Integer) As Short
Declare Auto Function dc_anticoll Lib "dcrf32.dll" (ByVal icdev As Integer, ByVal bcnt as Short, snr As Integer) As Short

...
```

Comment: I hope it was of some help to you.

Comment: That was very helpful, i can move on to the next level in my project. :)
thank you Mark.
I really don't have a discussion partner in my college about this RF ID thing. 
So, i feel hopeless for a while, but i found this excellent forum. 
Thanks for everyone :)

Maybe i would like to help some people around here, and ask some question about my project. Hehe

Comment: @ArvidTheodorus If this answered your question please click the check mark next to it so it shows up in the system as answered. Thanks

Comment: Ok, sorry i'm a newbie here :)