# RFID Programming With VB.NET | Part II

Tags: vb.net, rfid

This post is related to a post before this one :
[RFID Programming With VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337204/rfid-programming-with-vb-net)

Thanks for the answer Mark, i already change those to integer (because it doesnt match when port as long but the dc_init as Integer) i decided to change everything with Integer. And it works.

Now, i'm having another problem.
After the dc_init works (after i change those datatype to integer) i'm having a problem when calling dc_cards function.

For further information about the dc_init function i also include the manual file (from the RFID starter pack)

Here is the things that you need to see :
[Download](http://www.4shared.com/folder/JRpI__39/SecondProblem.html)

I'm sorry i can't explain more specific about this problem, because i can't post images and only 2 link that i can include. Maybe it would help by downloading those thing above. It includes my project in VB.NET, and the VB6 example program (it works and no bug at all), the dcrf32.dll file (copy them to system32 the driver for RFID).

I'm doing this in VB.NET according to VB6 sample program (from the starter pack), but it's kind of difficult since migrating VB6 to VB.NET.

i really strange with this code, i never learn it and i don't know what to do. Maybe Mark could help me further in my situation.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the dc_card function

Comment: @MarkHall
when i operate 
st = dc_card(icdev, mode, snr)
the "st" variable should return 0 or 1 value, but when i print it with messagebox.show(st)
it have a value equals to "snr" variable.

I don't have any clue about this project. Cause i don't have a discussion partner in my university about this RFID things.

Thanks Mark since you helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The Declaration for the dc_card Function should be:

```
Declare Auto Function dc_card Lib "dcrf32.dll" (ByVal icdev As Integer, ByVal mode as Short, snr As Integer) As Short
```

You should be passing the icdev you got from the dc_init function, and the mode of 0, your information will be in the snr variable and the status will be in st.

```
st = dc_card(ByVal icdev, cardmode, snr)
```

in your declares:

```
Dim snr, tagtype as Integer
Dim cardmode as Short

...
```

Comment: I'm sorry but in VB.NET  i cannot do this things :
st = dc_card(ByVal icdev, cardmode, snr)

no like in VB6, i can write ByVal when calling dc_card function, but in VB.NET it's not allowed.

Now i'm passing to another method to finish this proeject. Thanks anyway fot your answer Mark :)